# electron package: reduce the package size

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I made a simple [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app:

*main.js*

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600, 
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.ico')
  })

  win.maximize();

  win.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com/', {"extraHeaders" : "pragma: no-cache\n"});

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('browser-window-created',function(e,window) {
    window.setMenu(null);
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.test.app",
    "copyright": "test",
    "productName": "test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.7.9",
    "electron-builder": "^19.46.4",
    "electron-packager": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

with [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) i have builded the package to release:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

the total size of the builded package is **107 MB**.

Anyone have tips to reduce the size of the package?

Comment: Did you take a look at: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003 ?
Contributors to electron projects say that it's the expected size, because windows adds a copy of Git to the app, and also, you'll have some parts of Chrome in your application making it huge for no visible reasons.

If you're planning on distributing your application over the internet, I'd highly recommand you to zip your application before allowing downloads. See: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 (Nginx tutorial)

Answer (score 31):

You can reduce the electron app size by packaging using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) package.

[PicArt](https://github.com/bharathvaj1995/picart) is an **electronjs** app which I developed recently. It is built using **reactJS**. Initially when I packaged the app using electron-packager the Window's build size was around ***98 MB***. Then I found this awesome boilerplate [electron-react](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) where they configured the electron-builder to produced optimised build size. After using those configuration setup, PicArt's build is now around ***36 MB***.

Yes, it is possible to reduce the app size , but it quite painful and time consuming to configure the build setup.

Comment: I am using Vue with electron, so is there equivalence boilderplate for Vue?

Comment: @K.Symbol yes. you can find it [here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)

Comment: Yeah, one month before when I started building my app I considered it, but I finally choosed the https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/. The packaged .exe is 93.1MB, and 60MB after zipping, now I think acceptable.

Comment: That's an awesome boilerplate. Is there one that doesn't have so much custom code in it? Something more bare bones.

Answer (score 22):

I managed to reduce the final size of my mac app from **250MB** to **128MB** by moving 'electron' and my reactJs `dependencies` to `devDependencies` in `package.json` ...
since all I need is going to be in the final bundle.js

But sadly I couldn't get it any lower than that because the electron framework is **118MB** which is something if you're making a small app, but I guess that's the price to pay for making cross-platform web apps

Answer (score 7):

I've run into the same issue with an app of 200MB. Managed to get it down to 176MB and finally 55MB.

Here's what I did (if it helps):

- **Electron-builder**: To package app
- **Pruning: To clean** up unused modules
- **Cleaning up package.json file**: dependencies

**Packaging the App:**

Note:  I made a Windows application.

There's a two-step package.json method mentioned in the docs, but after trying myself (and confirming the docs) it's not needed.

Strangely enough for me what worked was deleted my entire 'Node Modules' folder, and running 'npm install' to bring everything back. Immediately after that, I ran 'npm prune' to clean out anything in the 'Node Modules' folder that isn't being used (even though I just ran 'npm install'). I also double-checked that neither electron nor electron-builder was in my 'dependencies' section in the package.json file. After this, I packaged the app/

As everyone probably already knows, With electron-builder, your 'dist' folder (unless you changed the default directory) should contain a `.exe` file directly in the 'dist' directory and an 'unpackaged' folder containing a `.exe` file which is contingent on the related files inside that same folder. However, the `.exe` file I have (the one that is directly within the 'dist' folder) is only 55MB. Although to be fair, this file does install the program and the size does inflate back to around 171MB once installed.

I Will post again if I can find another way to reduce the file size at all.

Comment: that is because the portable exe or the setup exe just zips the whole folder for you. so zipping it yourself would have the same effect. the electron folder itself stays the same 200mb+ (electron 23)

Answer (score 6):

The **Electron version** is important for reducing the package size.

**The minimum package size on Windows x64 without CEF recompiling**:

- `Electron v16.0.2` with `Chromium v96` => 52.9MB
- `Electron v3.1.13` with `Chromium v66` => 32.4MB

> You can choose your best version electron from [here](https://github.com/electron/releases)

**How to reduce size again after version choosed**:

1. Remove unused files for your cusomer, such as `d3dcompiler_47.dll`
2. Use a better compress algorithm, such as `7zip`

**All necessary files for Electron v3 packaging on Windows for example:**

```
└─App
    │  App.exe
    │  content_shell.pak
    │  ffmpeg.dll
    │  icudtl.dat
    │  natives_blob.bin
    │  node.dll
    │  v8_context_snapshot.bin
    │
    ├─locales
    │      en-US.pak
    │
    └─resources
           App.asar
           electron.asar
```

Comment: Can you detail how you came to the understanding that only those files are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Had a problem with a to big portable app exe going to **740MB**. Everyday I rebuild it was changing and I was very confused. (140MB, 340MB, 140MB, 740MB)

It is a Angular (16.0.5) Electron (25.1.0) build and I used this very helpfull template for it:
https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/blob/main/electron-builder.json

The Angular dist build is around 80MB with all assets like music and videos.

After looking what happens I found out that the files in **electron-builder.json** are not really well defined in this template.

```
 "files": [
    "**/*",
    "!**/*.ts",
    "!*.map",
    "!package.json",
    "!package-lock.json",
    {
        "from": "../dist",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
    },
```

It is also copying all node_modules and the src folder including all assets and all the json and configs from root additionally.

I changed it like this, to specify only files that are needed:

```
"files": [
    "app/*.js*",
    "app/*/*.js*",
    "app-scripts/copy-config.js", <-- extra file that I needed
    "!**/*.ts",
    "main.js",
    {
        "from": "dist",
        "filter": ["**/*"],
        "to": "app"
    }
],
```

Now the portable app exe is **143MB** not **740MB** anymore.

The node_modules folder is not needed even if you use electron functions like:

```
import {app, BrowserWindow} from 'electron';
import {join, normalize, resolve} from 'path';
import {appendFile, existsSync, mkdirSync, readFile, readFileSync, writeFile} from 'fs';
```

Hope this is helpfull also for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question while trying to lower my app as well. I'm creating an app with just the plain old HTML, CSS, and JS so I think it contributed to how small mine is relative to those in here. I think another factor is that it's still a small app so I really can't say but from what I've noticed, my earlier versions were heavier and slowly, I tried optimizing the directories and files.

After modifying my `packacge.json`'s `files` property [Crefelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76472498/7619826), it now looks like this:

```json
"files": [
    "!*",
    "!**/*",
    "main.js",
    "public/**/*"
],
```

The `main.js` is my entry point while all files in the `public` directory are those bundled and compiled via Laravel Mix (which uses webpack). All HTML are also located there.

Furthermore, I moved all my NPM packages to `devDependencies`, aside from the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.1.0",
    "electron-log": "^5.0.0",
    "electron-reloader": "^1.2.3",
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0"
},
```

My `devDependencies` now looks like this since then:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^23.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.76.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@sweetalert2/theme-dark": "^5.0.15",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "randexp": "^0.5.3",
    "semver": "^7.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.16.9",
    "textfit": "^2.4.0"
},
```

Following (@Bobbyv231's answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466353/7619826], I managed to at least shred a good 90MB+