# Electron app size is 450 mb for linux and 238 mb for windows, how to reduce it with respect to visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, electron-packager

I have built an electron app and packaged it using electron packager. I made windows bundle of 238MB and linux version is 450 MB. I compare this with visual studio code which is also electron app. They have relatively very low file size of 50 MB for windows and 60 to 70 MB for rpm and deb packages.

My app  is a simple, whereas visual studio code has more functionalities.

I want to reduce file size, how to do this?

I have already seen this , I am not using electron build but electron packager. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597283/electron-package-reduce-the-package-size)

Here is cmd I use inside package.json

```
packagerLinux: electron-packager --out Linux64 --overwrite --platform linux 
packagerWindows: electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform windows
```

Let me know if you need

Answer (score 6):

i am currently having the same issue and i spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to reduce the size of my 250MB Hello World package in Windows, obtained using electron-packager.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003) on it. To sum up briefly, the main problem is that Electron apps require both NodeJS and Chromium to be installed in order to work, so Electron packages contain both, increasing a lot the size of the file. This appears to be a non solvable problem.

Meanwhile, you can try to build the app using `npm run build --prod`, which reduces a bit the overall size of the folder.

**Edit**: i found out [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean) called **modclean**. It basically search your `node_modules` folder for unnecessary files and remove them.

Simply install it with

```
npm install modclean --save  //install locally
```

or

```
npm install modclean -g //install globally
```

and then launch it with `modclean` or `modclean -n default:safe`. 
In this way i managed to reduce the size of my final folder of around 30MB. Not a lot, but still something :)

Comment: Thanks Maffe :),  run build --prod will build do I need to pipe with packagerWindows: electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform windows

Comment: Yes, you can first build and then run electron-packager

Comment: Sure Maffe , I will try this and let you know if it works

Comment: npm run build  will look for script inside package.json right, what do I have in package.json for build script?